# run a batch file and a waitbar in matlab parallel

Tags: matlab, batch-file, parallel-processing, dos

I'd like to count my waitbar as long as the batch file is running.

Trials:

- `[status cmdout] = dos('test.bat &');  %the waitbar didn't know when the batch file ends.`
- `[status cmdout] = dos('test.bat');  %the waitbar starts after the batch file ends`
- With a function in which 1 is to run the batch file and 2 is the waitbar. The problem is, there's no possibility to display something in matpool.

  ```
  matlabpool(2)
      parfor i=1:2
         parallel_work(i);
      end
  matlabpool close
  ```

---

```
h = waitbar(0,'Initializing waitbar...');
t = timer('TimerFcn', 'stat=false;','StartDelay',180);
start(t)
stat=true;
cnt = 0;
while(status==false)
  perc = round(58+(42/180)*5*cnt);
  waitbar(perc/100,h,sprintf('%d%% ...',perc));
  pause(5)
  cnt = cnt + 1;
end
```

Comment: What is the question here? You seem to not have asked one.

Comment: On a sidenote for a moderator/high rep person to look at: I could not force code formatting around the matpool line. Pressing 'ctrl-k' did nothing but remove code formatting from the next block.

Comment: The question is, how could i run my waitbar as long as the batch file needs to be finished.

Comment: I suppose you could use a timer, as in the second part of your post? It won't be accurate but somewhat an indication.